# How to prove the following fact about the matrix exponential?

Tags: linear-algebra

Asking kindly, how to prove that $$\frac{e^{At} − I}t→A$$  as $t→0$ , meaning $\|(e^{At} −I)/t−A\|→0$  as $t→0$  for all $A∈ C_{n×n}$  . Hint: You may use the inequality $\|A^k \|≤ n^{k-1}\|A\|^k$.

Comment: pleas use latex

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You mean $e^{At}$.

Comment: It's e to the power of At.

Comment: I changed $||A||$ to $\|A\|$, etc.  That is standard usage.

Comment: Are you using the power series definition of the matrix exponential?

Comment: it is n to the power of k-1

Comment: @anon Is there another one? The power series definition is the standard, as far as I know.

Comment: im not too sure anon im just having trouble with it.

Comment: @George $\LaTeX$ is the math formatting tool we use here.  It is used for much more than just that, however: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Potato: there is a differential equation definition: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{At}=Ae^{At}$ and $e^{A\cdot0}=I$.

Comment: @Potato It's standard in linear algebra, yes. (Other definitions, the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) in Lie theory, or the fundamental solution to the system $X'=AX$, $X(0)=I$ in differential equations.)

Comment: @robjohn I was not aware! I think the question should be interpreted using the power series definition, though. Otherwise it is trivial. (Admittedly, it is fairly trivial the other way too...)

Comment: @Potato: I agree that the probable intention was the power series definition. I was simply responding to your question to anon. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the series definition of $\exp$. With the differential equation definition, the answer is trivial.

We have
$$
e^{tA}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(tA)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}t^k\frac{A^k}{k!}=I+tA+t^2\frac{A^2}{2}+\ldots.
$$
So for all $t\neq 0$
$$
\frac{e^{tA}-I}{t}-A=\sum_{k\geq 2}t^{k-1}\frac{A^k}{k!}.
$$

Case 1) If $\|A^k\|\leq \|A\|^k$ for all $k$ (which is the case with any Banach algebra norm on the matrices, eg with any induced operator norm), we get, for all $0<|t|\leq 1$: 
$$
\|\frac{e^{tA}-I}{t}-A\|\leq \sum_{k\geq 2}|t|^{k-1}\frac{\|A\|^k}{k!}\leq |t| \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{\|A\|^k}{k!}
$$
hence
$$
\|\frac{e^{tA}-I}{t}-A\|\leq|t| e^{\|A\|}\qquad \forall\; 0<|t|\leq 1.
$$
Now letting $t$ tend to $0$, we see by the squeeze theorem that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{tA}-I}{t}-A=0
$$
which proves the result.

Case 2) If you use a special norm and only have $\|A^k\|\leq n^{k-1}\|A\|^k$, the estimate becomes
$$
\|\frac{e^{tA}-I}{t}-A\|\leq|t|\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{n^{k-1}\|A\|^k}{k!}=\frac{|t|}{n}\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{n^{k}\|A\|^k}{k!}\leq \frac{|t|}{n}e^{n\|A\|}
$$
where the rhs tends to $0$ again as $t$ tends to $0$. So the squeeze theorem yields the result as in 1).

Comment: is that the full answer or do i have to let t tend to 0

Comment: @George I'll phrase it differently if you find it confusing like that.

Comment: so would i need to include part 2 in the whole answer?

Comment: @George What is the norm? If it's a standard operator norm, you only need case 1. If it is a special norm for which you only know the estimate given in the hint, don't mention case 1 and do case 2 directly.

Comment: @George when you don't know when a proof is finished, than you didn't unterstand him , so it's better to ask what he is doing than to ask what you need

Comment: what i ahve put in the question is the only informationa proided so what one do you think it is or what one do you think i should use?

Comment: @George  Then it is definitely case 2.

Comment: why did you use n on the lhs?

Comment: @George What do you mean? Why did I factor out $n^{-1}$ into $\frac{|t|}{n}$? So that I can easily bound the remaining sum by $e^{n\|A\|}$. For this, I needed $n^k\|A\|^k=(n\|A\|)^k$ at the numerator.

Comment: oh ok thanks very much. so i should use case 2 then.

Comment: @George Yes, go with case 2.

Comment: @George I rejected your edit. When an answer pleases you and answers your question, it is more usual to accept it by clicking on the accept button on the left, than to edit it to destroy it...